# Jupyter on Azure can not be reached

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-virtual-machine, azure-dsvm

I can not access Jupyter notebook on Data science VM in Azure clould.

What I did:

1. create a Data Science VM for Linux. Resource group, NSG, etc are newly created.
2. follow the instruction of the command `dsvm-more-info`. That is

   1. set `c.NotebookApp.password` (u'sha1:89this89is89a89fake89')
   2. restart jupyter
3. access https://12.34.56.78:9999/ (The IP address is of course a fake.)

But I can not establish any connection to the server.

- SSH works without any problem.
- NSG looks OK: TCP/9999 is allowed from all (This is the default setting.)
- I tried to https://localhost:9999/ on the VM, but no connection is established.
- http://12.34.56.78:9999/ is not working. (Just in case.)
- `c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'` changes nothing.
- My subscription is a test version. Is this relevant?
- Following Jupyter Documentation, I created mykey.key and mycert.pem and
  added absolute paths to the files in `jupyter_notebook_config.py`. But
  this does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Jupyter notebook is accessed through JupyterHub. You sign in using
>   your local Linux user name and password.

So, you should connect Jupyter notebook from port 8000, not 9999.

You can access the Jupyter notebook server from any host. Just type `https://<VM DNS name or IP Address>:8000/`

You also could use `netstat -ant` to check port listening on your VM. Port 9999 is not listening. So, you could not get it from port 9999.

More information about Jupyter on Azure Data science VM please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-data-science-linux-dsvm-intro#how-to-access-the-linux-data-science-virtual-machine). You could check `Jupyter notebook`.

Answer (score 7):

You can connect to Jupyter Notebook if you are running it on Ubuntu.

Assuming your jupyter notebook will be running on port:8888 on Azure VM.
First you have to create a SSH tunneling:

On your local computer type:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8888 username@server_address
```

Then on Azure start a notebook

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

Finally, open http://localhost:8080 in a web browser on your local machine.